# Difference between Tellurium and selenium 2

Tags: testing, selenium

In which scenarios should I use Tellurium against Selenium? From the basic reading, the only major difference I found is that Tellurium encapsulates the UI with the module concept. But selenium 2 has the PageObject serving the similar purpose. So appreciate if someone can let me know which framework to choose in what scenarios!

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The choice for me anyway is easy. I would pick Selenium. The amount of support and community around it makes picking this a lot easier, any issues you run into will be able to be solved much more quickly. One thing with selenium too is that it updates very often with support for latest browser releases which with the new release schedule for firefox is very important for multi browser support. Selenium also has drivers for testing your web app on mobile phones which is increasingly important as this is how a massive amount of web traffic is driven.

Any other questions just ask.